# How to Print the sum of all the consecutive negative values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sum

I wish to print the sum of all the consecutive negative values of a list

Example

```
lst = [1,-1,-3,2,3,4,-5,-1,-3,5,-3,-1,5,4]
```

I want to print the sum of :

```
(-1, -3) ;(-5,-1,-3); (-3,-1)
```

Comment: Write your code and your error, and we'll see what we can do.

Comment: start with a basic for loop, and then think about how to reduce the line numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) in a list comprehension:

```
lst = [1,-1,-3,2,3,4,-5,-1,-3,5,-3,-1,5,4]

from itertools import groupby
out = [sum(g) for k,g in groupby(lst, lambda x: x<0) if k]
```

output: `[-4, -9, -4]`

Answer (score 1):

```py
def sum_consecutive(values):
    accumulator = 0
    for value in values:
        if value >= 0:
            if accumulator != 0:
                print(accumulator)
            accumulator = 0
        else:
            accumulator += value
```

Should work